# Would like some recommendations for a historical and/or survival camping trip?

Tags: history, recommendations, drink, occasions

**Would like some recommendations for a historical and/or survival camping trip for two weeks this summer?**

We are planning to do a survival camping trip and hopefully making it as historical or traditional as possible. I am not holding recommendations to these parameters if logic or reasoning is justified. Plans are starting to get made for both food and drink.

For example, I have already started making hardtack and will be making pemmican this spring. The hardtack I have made takes soaking of 45 minutes to one hour to soften up enough to eat in hot coffee.

Any recommendations for drinks and/or food would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing more ancient to me in terms of drinks than drinking **mead** out of a horn in the middle of the woods.

For medieval markets, this is my go to drink to feel like historical viking, knight or whatever. On that note also I would suggest Red Wine in a fancy looking vase or piston.
[image]

To sum up: I really appreciate the idea and I'm thinking now, I should do a trip like this as well! Hope you're having fun, whatever you're doing or drinking.

Comment: Thanks Horsty I will definitely keep this in n mind

Answer (score 2):

Another interesting option for a historically based libation for survival camping, would be [Shackelton Whisky](https://www.theshackletonwhisky.com/discover-shackleton-whisky/) which is a blended Scotch designed to replicate the recipe of the Scotch Ernest Shackleton's expedition took to Antartica. I have a couple of bottles of it but I haven't tried it yet, so no guarantees as to how good it is.

Comment: Thank you Xander for your thoughts on this. Sounds like a genuinely good idea.

Comment: Xander - to help you out, it is delicious. I won some at a whisky tasting event a few years back and really enjoyed it!

Comment: @RoryAlsop Good to know!  I need to open it up soon...